# Laravel collection by month

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I've got a collection and I need the total users by month.

So I've done this:

```
array_replace(array_fill_keys(range(0, 11), 0), $users->groupBy('created_at.month')->toArray())
```

It's sort of working because I get this:

```
array:12 [▼
  0 => 0
  1 => 0
  2 => 0
  3 => 0
  4 => 0
  5 => 0
  6 => array:1 [▶]
  7 => array:2 [▶]
  8 => 0
  9 => 0
  10 => 0
  11 => 0
]
```

The problem I face now is that I don't need the 2 arrays at position `6` and `7` but I need the counts.

So I was thinking of something like:

```
$users->groupBy('created_at.month')->count()->toArray();
```

But, that's obviously not working. Any ideas ?

Comment: try this one, it might work in your case `count($users->groupBy('created_at.month')->toArray())`, I'm not sure though

Comment: @SagarGuatam nope that will return one integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using [map](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-map) method

```
$collection->map(function ($item, $key) {
    return count($item);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, end up with this: `array_replace(array_fill_keys(range(0, 11), 0), $users->groupBy('created_at.month')->map(function($users) {
            return count($users);
        })->toArray());`